# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement gcc7 (from versions: )

Tags: python

I tried to install gcc7 from using command

```
pip install gcc7
```

as shown in https://pypi.org/project/gcc7/.

But I am getting the following error. Can someone suggest how to resolve this?

```
C:\Users\Harsha>pip install gcc7
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement gcc7 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for gcc7
```

This is my system information

```
C:\Users\Harsha>python --version
Python 3.7.3
```

And I upgraded the pip version also.

Comment: It is not a python dependency - https://askubuntu.com/questions/859256/how-to-install-gcc-7-or-clang-4-0#915751

Comment: then why does pypi.org gave that command

Comment: Are you talking about this? https://pypi.org/project/gcc7/

Comment: yes Gino Mempin

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about this: https://pypi.org/project/gcc7/, then it does **not** support Windows (you seem to be on Windows based on your command line prompt).

The latest version [0.0.9](https://pypi.org/project/gcc7/0.0.9/#files) only has wheels for Mac (so it installs fine on a Mac). An older version [0.0.7](https://pypi.org/project/gcc7/0.0.7/#files) has wheels for both Linux and Mac (so this older version installs fine on Linux). It does not have installation files for Windows, so you won't be able to install it on Windows.

This makes sense because `gcc` is not natively supported on Windows. You will have to find another way to somehow get `gcc` on Windows.

Comment: Please also provide the another way to install gcc. I have spent more than 2 days finding this.

Comment: @AnujSharma The question was _specifically_ about installing the Python package gcc7, which I've already answered here as not supported on Windows. If your question is for generally installing gcc on Windows, I suggest you post your own separate question. Though, make sure to search first, because [that's already been asked/answered many times before](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+install+gcc+on+windows). (I also don't own a Windows machine so I really can't answer for Windows).

Answer (score 1):

GCC is supported on Windows. You can install GCC on Windows using MinGW-w64. MinGW-w64 is a free and open-source compiler suite for Windows that includes GCC.
-Download the MinGW-w64 installer from the MinGW-w64 website.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).